# Will "Thief Gloves" and the "Master Thief" specialty stack?

Tags: bravely-default

I don't seem to receive a yield that gives me definite proof. Anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thief Gloves and Master Thief do not stack, unfortunately.

Comment: That's a little odd. So which goes? And is the other null? Thanks!

Comment: If you have Master Thief, then any other steal-increasing modifier is nullified.